# Catel: Create new DataWindowButtonStyle based on another 3rd party style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, catel

REF:  [Catel docs](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Window+and+DataWindow#WindowandDataWindow-StylingtheDataWindow)

Using Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5.1, Catel 4.4.

I have a DataWindow with the default Close button.  I would like to style that button using the [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/) Flat Button style.  If I had direct access to the DataWindow Close button (I think it's created at runtime), I'd apply the Flat Button style in the XAML, but I don't.

In the Catel docs, the comment says we should specify our own DataWindowButtonStyle.  Could I get an example of creating a new DataWindowButtonStyle where I can base it on the MahApps.Metro Flat Button style?

Please let me know if you have any questions or need more information.

Thanks!

Edit:  Here's what I've tried:

```
<catel:DataWindow.Resources>
    <!--  Compile Error:  A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the BasedOn property of type 'Style'.
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="DataWindowButtonStyle" BasedOn="{DynamicResource MetroFlatButton}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>    
    -->
    <!-- This compiles and runs, but doesn't work.
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="DataWindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    -->
    <!-- This compiles and runs, but doesn't work.
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Catel.MVVM;component/themes/generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style x:Key="DataWindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    -->
    <!-- Compiles and runs, but doesn't work. -->
    <Style x:Key="DataWindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
    </Style>
</catel:DataWindow.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define a new DataWindowButtonStyle resource and it should be applied automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I knew about the DataWindowButtonStyle resource from your documentation.  What I was hoping for was an example on how to do this.  Everything I've tried either won't compile or doesn't work.  I wanted to upload what I've tried but I'm not seeing a way to upload files.

Comment: Feel free to create a ticket in the official issue tracker of Catel, there you can upload files.

Comment: I don't think this is as much a bug as it is a lack of knowledge on my part.  I'm pretty sure I don't have the correct XAML so that the DataWindow uses my button style and not its own built-in style.  Of course, if any of my attempts I added to my original post ARE correct, please let me know and I'll retest.  If it fails, I'll add an issue to the Catel tracker.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The custom DataWindowButtonStyle must be defined in App.xaml application resources.

App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataWindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
      <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

I don't know why setting background property is not working. But other properties are working.